# Visual Studio 2010 - Web Site Project with several hundred images to Include in Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

We have an e-commerce site which has an images/products folder. Within the ‘products’ folder we have several hundred product images (about 1200 or them).

The designer will update product images and upload them to the SVN. I will get the new product images via SVN. When I open the project in VS > images > products > I will see the images but they are ‘not included’ in the project. This causes issues when we publish the site as these ‘not included’ images are not uploaded to the server.

**My solution has been to right-click > Exclude from Project (wait about 10-15min) then right-click > Include in Project (wait about 30min).**

I have tried to select the images individual, but when dealing with 1000 plus, I don’t always catch them all.

I am looking for any help in managing thousands of images with an designer who is adding images to this directory (outside of VS).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551107/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-include-content-files-into-asp-net-project-file/2587401#2587401

Comment: Thanks .. I missed that post. I used :

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="images\**\*.*" />
    <Content Include="pdf\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the follow:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="images\**\*.*" />
    <Content Include="pdf\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

within the Web.csproj.

I also notices that the .csproj file contained ALL the 1000's references to all the images.So I manually edited that file and removed all the 'images' entries.

Once you have the project open, then using Windows I added pic to the image directory.
I viewed them in VS (after a refresh) and the files showed but where excluded.

I closed the solution > opened the solution and the images appeared as included. PERFECT!

So my designer can now just dump pics into the images DIR and I dont have to worry.

Thanks!