# Automatically Include generated file in Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scaffolding

I'm writing an application that will enable the creation of SQL files within visual studio. The user will enter commands via the Package Manager console which will generate sql scrips and deposit them in a specific directory within the Visual Studio Project.

The problem I have is that, when the files are generated, they are present on the file system, but not in Visual Studio. This is expected of course, as I need to then go and actively include the files within Solution explorer, but this isn't what I want. I want the files to "Magically" appear in solution explorer immediately after they're generated.

I've seen various solutions to similar problems mostly featuring amendments to the .csproj file such as this

```
<Compile Include="Sql\**\*.sql" />
```

but this isn't what i'm looking for. What i'm after is similar to how, for example, Entity Framework or MvcScaffolding work, where files / folders just magically drop into the project when commands run in PMC. I'm aware this runs off T4 templating, but that seems like too complex a solution for a simple issue like this.

I should qualify that there's no voodoo going on in the creation of the files, just plain old File.Create() stuff.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438419/1754037) answer for a solution that worked for me.  I have the same use-case where code outputs flat files and I need to include this  output in the project.

At the end of your .csproj file add the following:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Sql\**\*.sql" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, T4 is the way to go. You don't want to be bothering with [older technologies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31257/Custom-Tools-Explained) for what you are trying to do.

Having said that, I wonder why is it required for the files to be added to the solution explorer? is it for source control purposes? (usually you don't want to source control auto generated files, you want to source control the original model).
Note that you could always click the 'show all' button and the files will appear in the solution explorer, without actually being a part of the solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The reason is precisely for Source control purposes. The generated sql files are just templates which developers will fill in properly post-generation.

Comment: Very well. However, it still strikes me as a very peculiar requirement. What is this Package Manager Console you are talking about (NuGet?). How and by whom are the SQLs generated? How and by whom are they used?

Comment: It's effectively a database migrations tool. You type in some arguments to the Console (and yes, "nuget" console), specifying the version number and a migration name, and the tool kicks out migration sql templates, to be filled in with the actual SQL that's needed for that particular migration. Very similar to the entity framework toolset, but for complicated reasons, we're not using that.

Comment: Is it a process that will be repeated multiple times? I mean that when you migrate, you go from A to B and then forget A. So you generate a lot of scripts, run them and bye bye. Is this the case?

(as I said, regarding your original question, T4 seems the way to go. I am trying to get more details about the process itself to see if I can maybe give you a different perspective on the problem)