# How do I programmatically add a file to a visual studio project in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a way to programmatically add a source file to the project, given a file path?

I am trying to work on a visual studio project in sublime text 2. I can build using a custom build:

```
{
   "cmd": ["c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}/../Project"
}
```

I can link libraries using `#pragma comment(lib, "path to library")`

I can include the new source files using `#include ""`

but I cannot add new source file to the project.

Is there any code that could do that?

In the end Filburt gave a brilliant answer here:
 [Is there a way to add source files to visual studio project from command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764403/is-there-a-way-to-add-source-files-to-visual-studio-project-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how you could do this.

1. You simply treat the project as XML and you edit that XML.
2. You use Visual Studio's COM/.NET APIs.

It is not (IMHO) easy to do it using the Visual Studio APIs but it is doable. Start at MSDN's "[How to: Get References to the DTE and DTE2 Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/68shb4dw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" and follow the links.

Comment: for DTE all the code I could fine is either in c# or VB. Is this supported in c++ at all?  If not.. can you please expand a little bit on how to treat my project as xml?

Comment: Since it is all COM, you can use it from pure C++ as well. See the linked page, it shows bits of C++.