# Include static files in Azure WebJob's publish-settings.json

Tags: azure, publish, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to specify in a WebJob's `webjob-publish-settings.json` file that a folder of static/flat files should be included?

**Update:** 
As per @davidebbo's suggestion, I've tried modifying the .csproj file, but without success.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\Templates\*.xslt" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I've tried both `BeforeBuild` and `AfterBuild`, and with/without the `$(ProjectDir)` variable, but the folder never appears in the bin directory.

Comment: Are you using .Net? If so, is it ASP.NET 5/Core or 4.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not something you can do using `webjob-publish-settings.json`. Instead, you can do this by setting the 'Copy to Output Directory' property of the relevant files to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this was the case but held out hope that there might be a way to at least do it at folder level rather than for each file.

Comment: I wonder if there is some way of doing this at the csproj level, along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551107/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-include-content-files-into-asp-net-project-file