# Including auto-generated static content in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My web application has a node process that runs things like transpilation and minification, and produces a bunch of output files.  We've had problems with our CI server not sending these auto-generated files out unless they were manually included in the project.

Manually including auto-generated files is a pain, is easy to forget, and just an all-around bad idea.

How can I get visual studio to just include everything under a specific folder, no matter what.  I just need these files to exist to my script loader can load them when needed.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438419/352552) I tried

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="2\application-base\**\*.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

to no avail.  After adding that I've tried building the solution, the project, re-building the project, none of which cause anything in that folder to show up in the solution explorer as included.

Comment: `\2\...` refers to a root directory on the drive, not the project. Try `2\...` (will make answer if it works, cant see anything else wrong)

Comment: @leppie - I tried it without the least `\` originally - that did nothing, so I tried the leading slash, which also did nothing

Comment: Just for kicks, do `**\2\...` it might be the directory is not in the root of the project/solution, and that should find it.

Comment: @leppie I tried `<Content Include="**\2\application-base\*.js" />` which also did nothing :(

Comment: And it you just put `Content ` in the main `ItemGroup` of the project? Any effect?

Comment: @leppie - huh, `<Content Include="2\application-base\**\*" />` in the main `<ItemGroup>` worked just great - I thought I had read that doing that would auto-expand the `<Content>` item to manually include every file there, so it would only work the first time. Is that not the case?

Comment: It would appear in the project then, but from the link, the `Visible` subitem should hide them if you dont want them to be shown. I dont really know about the `BeforeBuild` target, maybe not even being called (test with `Message` item in there if you want to hack further).

Comment: @leppie well in any even, your comment two up from here is the answer - can you post that please so I can accept and upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `Content` in the main `ItemGroup` of the project.

Ie

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="2\application-base\**\*" />
```