# Visual studio 2015 can't find fonts at location

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, sass

I'm having a weird issue with VS2015 after installing the WebCompiler for SASS.

Before installing the WebCompiler I had several css files . After installing the compile I converted those files in scss files manually. Somewhere along the way Visual Studio stopped finding my woff files although all the font-face's are pointing at the correct location.

My solution files are as follows:

[image]

And my font-face's look like this :

> @font-face {
>       font-family: LatoBlack;
>       src: url('../fonts/Lato-Black.woff');
>   }

Although intelisense is telling me that the url is the correct one and there is a file called Lato-Black.woff , when I run the application i get a 404 error.

Comment: You probaly need to include the new compiled version into the project?

Comment: Yes, that is what the Bundled.scss is for. It imports the new scss files into this single file and compiles all of the into one.

Comment: Im thinking of if the compiler deletes a file and creates it agian, then VS often require you to say -> show hidden files -> include into project.

Comment: But the compiler was not the one that deleted the old css files. I did that after copying the content of those files in new scss files and referencing those files instead. Also if the files show up in the Soltuion Explorer then that means Visual Studio already knows about them and that they are include in the assembly no?

Comment: No weird enough does VS not include them as solution files even though they are in the solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the solution not including the files automatically.

Here is an old thread telling how to auto include files in Visual Studio:

[Is there a way to automatically include content files into asp.net project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551107/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-include-content-files-into-asp-net-project-file/9438419#9438419)

Comment: I did check the .csproj file to see if the content files are include and everything seems to be in order, All the scss and woff files are included.