# Content-Only Projects in .NET Core

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Using .NET Core, is there a way to have content-only projects in Visual Studio 2017 (no output dlls but automatic copying of content for other projects)? I'm after essentially the same thing as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546393/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-content-data-only-project-in-visual-studio), save that I'm working with .NET Core.

I saw something about Shared Projects and wondered if that'd be the appropriate solution. Not exactly sure how they work with .NET Core, though (or if they're even supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging into how Shared Projects work. This appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, provided I don't encounter any major caveats or showstoppers down the road.

For others that are new to Shared Projects, they appear in a separate selection below Projects in the navigation tree of the Reference Manager (when adding project references).