# Automatic Build action for json files

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a *C# "Class Library"* type project in Visual Studio 2015.

At the moment when i add in the project files like : json files or pictures, Visual Studio sets the build action for these files as "None" . I need them to be set as "Content".

At the moment i am making this seeting manually. However i am adding a large amount of files of that in my project.

Is there a way i can instruct visual studio to set automatically the build action to "Content" when i add them ?
Also i need this option to be valid also on the TFS machine .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743432/how-can-i-automatically-add-existing-items-to-a-visual-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

From [this msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild) you can see that all files which are included in the build process have to be specified in a `.<something>proj` file, which is nothing more than a simple XML file.

For what you need I would unload the project within Visual Studio and open up the project file for edit. Find `<ItemGroup>` in that XML file and add `<Content Include="Path-to-your-JSON-files\*.json" />`.

---

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <CSFile Include="main.cs" />
    <!-- assume you have a bunch of these -->

    <Content Include="Path-to-your-JSON-files\*.json" />    
</ItemGroup>
```