# How can Emacs fans keep Visual Studio buffs happy when they collaborate on a Python project?

Tags: python, visual-studio, emacs

Victor is quite fond of Visual Studio. Edward is a die-hard Emacs fan. Victor and Edward work together on a Python project. Whenever Edward adds a .py file to the project, he does nothing. If it's on disk, then it's part of the project. Victor finds it tedious that he needs to "add file to project" much more often than he should.

Is there a pythonic way to specify, in some kind of configuration file, which files belong to the project/solution? Is there a way to continuously generate, in some automated way, VC project/solution files from the files on disk?

Comment: They can both reach some compromise and switch to VS Code

Comment: They can both reach some compromise and switch to VS Code

Comment: @yorodm You nailed it. Indeed the trouble is the culture (*nix vs Windows), and an IDE that is OS-neutral would go a long way to making everyone happy. However, IMO, compared to any of Emacs, PyCharm, or Visual Studio, VS Code feels like a primitive tool with a long sequence of missing features.

Comment: I'm a hard core Emacs fan so you're preaching to the choir

Comment: Is there a reason why this is the Emacs user's problem?  After all, if 10 different developers each had a different editor with its own editor-specific way of defining what was in a project, it would clearly be the responsibility of each developer to manage the idiosyncrasies of their own tooling -- requiring every developer to cater to the personal tools of everyone else would be absurd IMO, and that seems no different to me whether the number of developers is 10 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a solution would be to write some script that automatically adds the files to the project. [Automatically add existing items to a VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743432/how-can-i-automatically-add-existing-items-to-a-visual-studio-project). Link that to a scheduled task or a [git pull hook](https://gist.github.com/GianlucaGuarini/8001627) and Victor should be good to go.

Comment: cron job, on Windows? Am I missing something?

Comment: Scheduled task* sorry

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like more of a version control problem, than one of python or text editors/IDEs. The two team members should collaborate while using version control software, whether the now predominant [Git](https://git-scm.com/), or possibly [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/), or [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/).

Whether a version controlled archive is saved on a central server (commercial or otherwise) eg Github or any of it's competitors, or whether this is saved locally, I think this will relieve most of the issues in the collaboration.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit perplexed by this notion of a 'project' which is defined in an editor-specific way.  In this day and age, that makes no sense to me.  I would *hope* that if version-control was used, then Visual Studio would defer to that?!

Comment: Both Haziz and Phils have some very nice thoughts. An answer incorporating both streams of thoughts, and left open for others to modify, would be very great.