# Load new files VisualStudio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

My visual studio 2017 does not detect when git adds new files to the folder for some reason...

I don't want to manually add the file every time one gets creagted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find your answer here:
[Is there a way to automatically include content files into asp.net project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551107/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-include-content-files-into-asp-net-project-file/2587401#2587401)

Or, if you don't want to fiddle with that, the top answer here offers a faster way of manually adding files:
[How can I automatically add existing items to a Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743432/how-can-i-automatically-add-existing-items-to-a-visual-studio-project)